# Why do different search engines give me rather different results?

Tags: search-results

If I type a topic into "Google," I get one list of articles. If I type the same topic into, e.g. Ask.com, I usually get a rather different list. Or at least they are in very different orders. Why is that?

Naturally, each engine is different from each other, but I was under the impression that they operated under similar principles.  How do search engines work differently to produce such different results?

Comment: This question is about the algorithms employed by different search engines. It may be a possible fit on Webmasters.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Web contains many pages and alphabetical order will not work. You need to create your own algorithm. Each company may have different algorithms because of having different abstractions on what search is. From philosophical point of view, search and find is quite complicated actions.

Think like that when does a human think that he finds? When do you think that the information is ok to believe? Where are the lines? Nobody knows, it evolves like art. User experiences are unique and so may every search query can be unique too.

The core of the question is not only what search engine brings, what satisfies you as a user or question owner.